# Sum subtotal cart values WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have custom post type containing saved cart. Its looks like it has no any saved subtotal data of the whole cart, and I need to sum it in "foreach". The code is not working:

```
$cart = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wcssc_cart_data' );

if ( !empty( $cart ) ) {
  $cart = $cart[ 0 ];
}
foreach ( $cart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

  $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item\[ 'data'\ ], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
  $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item\[ 'product_id'\ ], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

  if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item\[ 'quantity'\ ] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {

    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

    ///MY CODE START
    $value1 = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal',
      WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item\[ 'quantity'\ ] ),
      $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

    $total_cart += $value1;
```

Do I need to get raw(without HTML tags) subtotal for each product and then do the sum, or I can do some calculations inside get_product_subtotal() ?[image]